# Unable to install some required packages in Red Hat Linux

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, rpm, package-management

I Have RHEL6.5. I mam trying to install some required packages.Here is the response

```
Error Downloading Packages:
  glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686: failure: Packages/glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686.rpm from Local: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

  cracklib-2.8.16-4.el6.i686: failure: Packages/cracklib-2.8.16-4.el6.i686.rpm from Local: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

  nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-9.el6.i686: failure: Packages/nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-9.el6.i686.rpm from Local: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try
.
  db4-4.7.25-18.el6_4.i686: failure: Packages/db4-4.7.25-18.el6_4.i686.rpm from Local: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

  libselinux-2.0.94-5.3.el6_4.1.i686: failure: Packages/libselinux-2.0.94-5.3.el6_4.1.i686.rpm from Local: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  pam-1.1.1-17.el6.i686: failure: Packages/pam-1.1.1-17.el6.i686.rpm from Local: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

  audit-libs-2.2-2.el6.i686: failure: Packages/audit-libs-2.2-2.el6.i686.rpm from Local: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.


Error code: 1
Failed to install pam.i686

#################################################################################################
ERROR: Failed to install some required packages. 
Verify if yum repository is configured. (yum repolist)
You could configure a local repository using the local.repo template in installation directory.
#################################################################################################
```

Here the output of yum repolist command:

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from Red Hat Subscription Management.
repo id                                                             repo name                                                                          status
Local                                                               Local Media Repository                                                             3,690
repolist: 3,690


exiting setup...
```

Comment: set up working repositories for yum (_"Verify if yum repository is configured."_)

Comment: Yes it is configured

Comment: You got struck??@IporSircer

Comment: Talk to the person who installed and customized the system.

Comment: But  what is the problem exactly  i have to say???

Answer (score 0):

I just navigated to package file location and installed directly.It worked

Thanks